# Pandas: plot all Y columns vs one X column

Tags: pandas, plot, scatter

How can I plot all Y columns vs one X column in an excel sheet, all in the same plot, as show in the picture below? In the real excel sheet, there are close to 30 columns.

[Data and picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lj54E.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the column name to the appropriate columns in your dataset:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("your_csv_file_here")
df = df.set_index("name_of_X_column")
df.plot()
```